# Laravel eloquent average score on foreign table

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to fetch some records if a certain condition is met, but am having trouble building the correct query.

Here's my example code:

```php
// $stars_selected = "4"


  $brokers = Broker::query()
  ->with('avgScore');  // example will returns 3.5
  ->paginate(10)
  ->withQueryString();
```

Now, let's say I have another variable present `$stars_selected = "4"`, and I only want to fetch records that have a `avgScore` greater that 4.0. How would I accomplish this?

I've tried writing it like this:

```php
$brokers = Broker::query()

if ($stars_selected) {
  $brokers->with(['avgScore' => function ($query) {
      $query->where('avgScore', '>=', floatval($_GET['stars']));
  }]);
}

$brokers = $brokers
  ->paginate(10)
  ->withQueryString();
```

But I'm getting an error: `Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'avgScore' in 'where clause'`

I also have this i my Broker model.

```php
    public function avgScore()
    {
        return $this->reviews()
            ->selectRaw('avg(score) as aggregate, broker_id')
            ->groupBy('broker_id');
    }

    public function getAvgScoreAttribute()
    {
        if (!array_key_exists('avgScore', $this->relations)) {
            $this->load('avgScore');
        }
        $relation = $this->getRelation('avgScore')->first();
        return ($relation) ? $relation->aggregate : null;
    }
```

Comment: you should also indicate the database relationship on your question

Answer (score 2):

I reviewed your code there's nothing wrong.
check the name of the column In foreign table I think it should be (aggregate) because you're return it as (aggregate)

```
$brokers->with(['avgScore' => function ($query) {
      $query->where('aggregate', '>=', floatval($_GET['stars']));
  }]);
```

Comment: In the first example when I query ```->with('avgScore')```, the value of 3.5 is returned as expected. This is the average of all scores for that particular record. How do I include a condition 'only where avgScore is equal to or above $stars_selected' ? Pseudo code, obviously. Sorry, but I don't understand your solution.

Comment: I edit my answer, please try this solution

Comment: The closest I came to was with ```$query->having('aggregate', '>=', floatval($_GET['stars']));```, but sadly it's giving me wrong results. I ended up doing the score comparison in blade template, which is unnecessarily fetching more records from the DB, but at least it's working. I'm keeping it as unresolved until I find a better solution via a query. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

If you're on Laravel 8 you can use the `withAvg` aggregate method, which was  introduced recently.

```
Broker::query()
    ->withAvg(relation: 'reviews', column: 'score') // results in 'reviews_avg_score' column 
    ->where('reviews_avg_score', '>=', floatval($_GET['stars']))
    ->paginate()
    ->withQueryString();
```

Docs: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#other-aggregate-functions

Comment: This almost works but I still get an error that it can't find the aggregated column.
The generated sql without the where clause does add the column reviews_avg_score to the result. But if you add the where clause it fails to find reviews_avg_score even though it is in the result

select `posts`.*, (select avg(`reviews`.`rating`) from `reviews` where `posts`.`id` = `reviews`.`post_id`) as `reviews_avg_rating` from `posts`     

This results in column reviews_avg_score add to results but where clause fails

Answer (score 0):

It's been awhile since I've coded in Laravel, but does this fix your problem?

```php
  $brokers = Broker::query()
  ->with('avgScore')
  ->where('avgScore', '>=', floatval($_GET['stars']))
  ->paginate(10)
  ->withQueryString();
```

I'm assuming the `Broker::query()` returns a query object, that you can then chain on additional stipulations, so you should be able to include the 'where' clause directly.

Or, for your 'full' example, something like this:

```php
$brokers = Broker::query()->with('avgScore');

if ($stars_selected) {
  $brokers = $brokers->where('avgScore', '>=', floatval($_GET['stars']));
}

$brokers = $brokers
  ->paginate(10)
  ->withQueryString();
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work. I can fetch the records with ```->with('avgScore')``` but when I include ```->where('avgScore', '>=', floatval($_GET['stars']))``` I'm getting the following error: ```Unknown column 'avgScore' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `brokers`...```. FWIW, when I only do the first, my json results look something like this: ```"avg_score":[{"aggregate":3.5,"broker_id":1}],```

Comment: Ahhh, okay, what if you tried `$brokers->where('aggregate', '>=', floatval($_GET['stars']));`?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a one to many relationship between brokers and reviews table,
What you are trying to achieve can simply be done by using joins:

```
$stars_selected = '4';

$avg_reviews = DB::table('reviews')
                ->select(DB::raw("avg(score) as aggregate,broker_id"))
                ->groupBy('broker_id');

$broker_reviews = Broker::leftJoinSub($avg_reviews,'broker_avg_reviews', function($join){
    $join->on('brokers.id','=','broker_avg_reviews.broker_id');
})->where('aggregate','>=',$stars_selected);

$brokers = $broker_reviews->paginate(10);
```